# Error in running swirl package in R

Tags: r, package, swirl

I am not able to work in swirl package in R. I am able to install the swirl 
package correctly. But while giving the library("swirl") command the error comes up.I have tried every thing like I am not able to find the answer of this error on internet. I have reinstalled R complete. I have tried changing directory. But still this error message is coming. Please help.This is the error message:

> library("swirl")
>   Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) :
>     cannot open file
>   'C:/Users/Devender/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/httr/R/httr.rdb': No such
>   file or directory
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’
>   Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `httr` package. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: ThankYou very much for the reply. I have installed httr package again(install.packages("httr")). But still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say which R version you are using.

Some Swirl packages are not available for few R versions as 3.2.2. You cant even download any courses from Github repositories into the Swirl if Swirl was successfully loaded in R.

You may want to re-install a different version of R to avoid this Swirl issue, and try again.